# Substitute for wait and notify in java

Tags: java, synchronization, wait, notify

Is there any substitute for wait/notify in java ?

I have two threads:

```
thread1:
run() {
 while(true) {      
  data = getDataFromDatabase()
  changedData = performSomeChanges(data)
  commitUpdateDataToDatabase(changedDate)
  (send signal to thread2 to start and wait for signal for next repetition)
 }  
}

thread2:
run() {
 while(true) {      
  (wait for signal from thread1)
  data = getDataFromDatabase()
  changedData = performSomeChanges(data)
  commitUpdateDataToDatabase(changedDate)
  (send signal to thread1)      
 }  
}
```

and I want have some kind of synchranization between them. Now I use wait / notify on special common  Object for this purpose.

Comment: wouldn't an observer pattern solve your issue? without having to rely on synchronization? or perhaps some Futures might come in handy here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `wait` and `notify`?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the simple way to implement your example only uses one thread:

```
run() {
    while(true) {
        // old thread 1 code      
        data = getDataFromDatabase()
        changedData = performSomeChanges(data)
        commitUpdateDataToDatabase(changedDate)
        // old thread 2 code
        data = getDataFromDatabase()
        changedData = performSomeChanges(data)
        commitUpdateDataToDatabase(changedDate)
    }  
}
```

There is no obvious (to me) advantage in having the execution alternate between two threads.  And there a couple of obvious disadvantages; i.e. complexity, and the (smallish) performance hit of the synchronization and thread switching.

---

But assuming that you do have a legitimate reason for alternating between two threads, then there are lots of ways of doing it:

- Using `wait` and `notify` ... as you are currently doing.  (IMO, there is no real *need* to find an alternative.  They work just fine, if used properly!  Admittedly, some Java programmers haven't mastered this ...)
- Using [`java.util.concurrent.Semaphore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) and having each thread alternate between acquiring and releasing.
- Using a `java.util.concurrent.Lock` and alternating ownership of the lock.
- Using a `BlockingQueue` and passing a "token" object back and forth.
- And so on